# Rails: Filterrific not updating scope. New scope won't load in view

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, filterrific

I am attempting to use the filterrific gem to create a basic filter on my index page.  Unfortunately filterrific does not appear to be talking to my database.  When I run the server and use the drop down menu to `sort_by` the new partial is rendered but the scope is not changed.

```
Started GET "/wikis?utf8=%E2%9C%93&filterrific%5Bsearch_query%5D=&filterrific%5Bsorted_by%5D=title_asc&_=1499629014459" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-09 12:48:29 -0700
Processing by WikisController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "filterrific"=>{"search_query"=>"", "sorted_by"=>"title_asc"}, "_"=>"1499629014459"}
  Wiki Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `wikis`.* FROM `wikis`
  Rendered wikis/_list.html.erb (4.2ms)
  Rendered wikis/index.js.erb (5.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 6.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

As well, the `default_filter_params` are not affecting the displayed scope either.

The scopes that I have defined work perfectly in the console so I am sure that they are correct.

Here is my model

```
 class Wiki < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :collaborators
  validates :body, presence: true
  validates :title,
    presence: true,
    uniqueness: { case_sensitve: false, scope: [:year]},
    length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 254}

  enum category: [:adventure, :dual_sport, :sport, :naked,
    :touring, :cruiser, :custom, :dirt, :roadster]

  enum final_drive: [:belt, :chain, :shaft]

  filterrific(
    default_filter_params: { sorted_by: 'title_asc'},
    available_filters: [
      :sorted_by,
      :search_query
    ]
  )

  scope :search_query, lambda { |query|
    return nil  if query.blank?

    terms = query.downcase.split(/\s+/)

    terms = terms.map { |e|
      (e.gsub('*', '%') + '%').gsub(/%+/, '%')
    }
    num_or_conds = 2
    where(
      terms.map { |term|
        "(LOWER(students.first_name) LIKE ? OR LOWER(students.last_name) LIKE ?)"
      }.join(' AND '),
      *terms.map { |e| [e] * num_or_conds }.flatten
    )
  }

  scope :sorted_by, lambda { |sort_option|
    direction = (sort_option =~ /desc$/) ? 'desc' : 'asc'
    case sort_option.to_s
    when /^title_/
      order("wikis.title #{ direction }")
    when /^cylinders_/
      order("wikis.cylinders #{ direction }")
    when /^hp_/
      order("wikis.hp #{ direction }")
    when /^torque_/
      order("wikis.torque #{ direction }")
    when /^displacement_/
      order("wikis.displacement #{ direction }")
    when /^year_/
      order("wikis.year #{ direction }")
    else
      raise(ArgumentError, "Invalid sort option: #{ sort_option.inspect }")
    end
  }

  def self.options_for_sorted_by
    [
      ['Title (a-z)', 'title_asc'],
      ['HP (most)', 'hp_desc'],
      ['HP (least)', 'hp_asc'],
      ['Torque (most)', 'torque_desc'],
      ['Torque (least)', 'torque_asc'],
      ['Year (oldest)', 'year_desc'],
      ['Year (newest)', 'year_asc'],
      ['Displacement (most)', 'displacement_desc'],
      ['Displacement (least)', 'displacement_asc'],
      ['Cylinders (most)', 'cylinders_desc'],
      ['Cylinders (least)', 'cylinders_asc'],
    ]
  end
end
```

My controller

```
...

def index
    @wikis = Wiki.all
    @filterrific = initialize_filterrific(
      Wiki,
      params[:filterrific],
      select_options: {
        sorted_by: Wiki.options_for_sorted_by,
      },
      available_filters: [:sorted_by]
    ) or return

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
      puts "Had to reset filterrific params: #{ e.message }"
      redirect_to(reset_filterrific_url(format: :html)) and return
  end
...
```

My views

views/wikis/index.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div>
        <%= form_for_filterrific @filterrific do |f| %>
        <div>
          Search
          <%= f.text_field(
            :search_query,
            class: 'filterrific-periodically-observed'
          ) %>
        </div>
        <div>
          Sorted by
          <%= f.select(:sorted_by, @filterrific.select_options[:sorted_by]) %>
        </div>
        <div>
          <%= link_to(
            'Reset filters',
            reset_filterrific_url,
          ) %>
        </div>
        <%= render_filterrific_spinner %>
        <% end %>

        <div>
          <%= render(
            partial: 'wikis/list',
            locals: { wikis: @wikis }
          ) %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

views/wikis/_list.html.erb

```
<div id="filterrific_results">
  <% wikis.each do |wiki| %>
    <h4>
      <%= link_to wiki.title, wiki %>
      (<%= wiki.year %>)
    </h4>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

views/wikis/index.js.erb

```
<% js = escape_javascript(
  render(partial: 'wikis/list', locals: { wikis: @wikis })
) %>
$("#filterrific_results").html("<%= js %>");
```

I have also included `//= require filterrific/filterrific-jquery` in application.js

There must be something I am missing to tie it all together but I am at a loss for what it might be.  I was initially using sqlight3 for my database and thought that was the problem so I have since changed to mysql2 as it is listed as supported in the filterrific docs.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You mentioned that you switched from sqlite to mysql because of having found something related to that in the documentation. I have the same issue (nothing is refreshed), and using sqlite. Could you please point to where you found this in the docs (I haven't)? Just as I'd like to figure out if in my case the problem is using sqlite or something else.

Comment: Near the top of the documentation [link](https://github.com/jhund/filterrific) it mentions compatibility and shows a chart.  On the chart it shows the database adaptors and it lists mysql2 and postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured out my error.

In the controller I was still defining `@wikis = Wiki.all` when I should have been defining it as `@wikis = @filterrific.find`.  That way the search performed by filterrifc will be stored in the `@wikis` variable.